# How to force page number right of the textbody

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, scrlayer-scrpage

I want the page number to appear in the footer right/left of the textbody. My implementation works as long as the page number has only one digit. The more digits, the more the page number moves towards/into the textbody.
To be honest it is kind of hard to put in words, so I attached a small illustration.
It would be great if someone of you could help me.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,titlepage=firstiscover]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[markcase=upper,headsepline=0.5pt,headwidth=165mm:-0mm:15mm,footwidth=155mm:-0mm:5mm]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{\headmark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image: page_number_problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the number in box that can stick out into the margin. Change the size of the box from 0pt to something else, if you want the number more inside.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,titlepage=firstiscover]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[markcase=upper,headsepline=0.5pt,headwidth=165mm:-0mm:15mm,footwidth=155mm:-0mm:5mm]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{\headmark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\rofoot{\makebox[0pt][l]{\pagemark}}
\lefoot{\makebox[0pt][r]{\pagemark}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{125}
Text \newpage text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, as I saw this answer first I used it and it worked like a charm. Thank you for the super fast reply.

Comment: @JohnKormylo \rlap is certainly faster, but it hasn't the optional argument to set the width.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\makebox` with a fixed width, left aligned for odd pages, right aligned for even pages:

```latex
\rofoot*{\makebox[1ex][l]{\pagemark}}
\lefoot*{\makebox[1ex][r]{\pagemark}}
```

Note that I have used the starred versions of the commands: then the settings for page style `plain` are changed too. Page style `plain` is used on chapter pages by default.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,titlepage=firstiscover]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in the example
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[
  headsepline=0.5pt,
  headwidth=165mm:0mm,% <- changed
  footwidth=155mm:0mm,% <- changed
  markcase=upper,
  automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\rofoot*{\makebox[1ex][l]{\pagenumberrule\pagemark}}
\lefoot*{\makebox[1ex][r]{\pagemark\pagenumberrule}}
\newcommand\pagenumberrule{\rule[-\ht\strutbox]{.4pt}{2\ht\strutbox}}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
% only for the example
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1001}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that I have removed the third argument of `headwidth` and `footwidth`. It is not needed in your code.

Comment: As I saw this answer slightly later, I did not use it directly. Out of curiosity I tried it and it also works fine.